# Show small Popup above highlighted text in Code mirror editor

Tags: html, jquery, css, codemirror

I am using the following code to highlight the text segment in Codemirror, a code editor and syntax highlighter, downloaded from [here](https://codemirror.net/).

I am not able to figure out from documentation how it is supposed to be implemented.

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
        var range = array[i].split("-");
        editor.getDoc().markText({
            line: parseInt(range[0].split(":")[0]) - 1,
            ch: parseInt(range[0].split(":")[1])
        }, {
            line: parseInt(range[1].split(":")[0]) - 1,
            ch: parseInt(range[1].split(":")[1])
        }, {
            css: "color : white; background-color: red; border: 1px;"
        });
}
```

Desired output (Not same as below, just for the clearance of concept)

[image: A sample image demonstrating what exactly is needed]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 120%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -30%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #555 transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">Wait.. Can you hover over me!
  <span class="tooltiptext">Suprise!</span>
</div>
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_tooltip.asp

Comment: Yes you are right i was using material, so for further optimizations i used materalizecss tool tip